# How get document path in order to delete/edit a document in firestore?

Tags: firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I'm testing the new firestore with ionic using [angularfire2](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2) and I'm able to list and create collections and documents following the documentation.

These are the [ts and html](https://gist.github.com/danielnv18/4bb1d77dc0860493d717692939b8e47e) file that I use in order to list a collection of documents.

According to the documentation in [github](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/documents.md#manipulating-documents) I can use the delete() and update() methods in `AngularFirestoreDocument` but since I have a collection of documents I need the document path to do something like this `this.chemicalsCollection.doc('path/1).delete()` or `this.chemicalsCollection.doc('path/1).update()`.

In the old days (last week) I could do something like this:

```
constructor(database: AngularFireDatabase) {
  this.itemsRef$ = this.database.list('items');
}
deleteItem(item) {
  this.itemsRef$.remove(item.$key)
}
```

and loop `itemsRef$` in the html `*ngFor="let item of chemicalsRef$ | async" (click)="deleteItem(item)"`. The index `$key` came from the firebase database but if I do the same with firestore there's no `$key` or `path` in the object, just the data I created.

What am I missing? how do I get the document's path?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are multiple ways of streaming data from a collection. I am guessing you are using `.ValueChanges()` which returns an Observable containing the JSON object data.
What you need to be using is `.snapshotChanges()`It returns an array with a lot more information. Then  you can use a map operator to get the data and the object Id from the array.

An example of this is show in the documentation under snapshotChanges():
[AngularFire GitHub Doc](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md)

Comment: I followed the snapshotChanges [example](https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/firestore/collections.md#snapshotchanges)  and it worked. Thanks